# Google Authorship on a multi-author blog?

Tags: author, multi-author, google-plus

I hav been having some difficulties getting authorship set up for a multi-author blog.  Everything appears to be set up correctly, but I am wondering if having multiple rel="author" tags on the home page is preventing the Google+ Profile of the main author from appearing in search results.

By default, the wordpress theme I am using uses 'the_author_posts_link()' when linking to other blog posts on the home page. and internal pages.(this automatically adds 'rel="author"' to the link).

Although, there is only 1 author profile who is actually linking to his Google+ Profile could have so many `rel="author"` tags be preventing his blog posts from displaying his Google+ Profile photo in the search results?

On the specific posts of the author who I am attempting to have Google authorship for, his link looks like this:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="author me" href="http://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxx" title="Google+"></a>
```

this link appears in the author box at the end of the authors' post.

When testing a url of a post by the said author in the rich-snippets-tool, everything looks great.  However, it doesn't appear that way in the search results.  I have tried several configurations of this, including using plugins and having the author link in the .

Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might take some time for the google to update this information to the search index.

As far i've seen the older posts on my blog (multi user) show the author information in a google search. The latest posts don't really get updated with that information.

**A post from Feb 2013**
 [image]

**Posts from a few days ago**
[image]

Comment: It's because Google has ended the authorship and image in SERPs program. Read https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en

Comment: @songdogtech It was available during the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Google has ended the authorship and image in SERPs program. Read https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=en